# How to search for name in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

For example I want to find all the people that has "Abbott" in their name

```
0                        Abbing, Mr. Anthony
1                Abbott, Mr. Rossmore Edward
2           Abbott, Mrs. Stanton (Rosa Hunt)
3                        Abelson, Mr. Samuel
4      Abelson, Mrs. Samuel (Hannah Wizosky)
                       ...                  
886                  de Mulder, Mr. Theodore
887                de Pelsmaeker, Mr. Alfons
888                del Carlo, Mr. Sebastiano
889          van Billiard, Mr. Austin Blyler
890              van Melkebeke, Mr. Philemon
Name: Name, Length: 891, dtype: object
```

df.loc[name in df["Name"]]
I tried this and it didn't work

```
'False: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'
```

Comment: You can use `df[df['Name'].str.contains['Abbott']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.contains` with the column you are interested in searching

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name': ['Smith', 'Jones', 'Smithson']})
>>> df
       Name
0     Smith
1     Jones
2  Smithson
>>> df[df['Name'].str.contains('Smith')]
       Name
0     Smith
2  Smithson
```